# Filling Dynamically Allocated Array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to fill up the multi-dimensional array using dynamic memory allocation and running into problem of how to determine the size of each array.

The sizes are also dynamically generated in the for loop, not sure how i can transport this knowledge into looping construct to tell the compiler when to stop.

Please dont answer the problem directly, just a direction needed so i can figure out on how to solve the problem of determining this,
for (int v = 0; v < sizeof(a[y]); v++)

```
int** a = new int*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        int colcount;

        cout << "Enter Size of Array for " << i << " : ";

        cin >> colcount;

        a[i] = new int[colcount];

    }

    // How to fill the matrix now

    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {

        for (int v = 0; v < sizeof(a[y]); v++) {

            cout << "Enter Array Content [" << y << "][" << v << "] :";

            cin >> a[y][v];

        }

    }
```

**Update:**
Got it working by bringing the for loop inside.

```
int** a = new int*[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    int colcount;

    cout << "Enter Size of Array for " << i << " : ";

    cin >> colcount;

    a[i] = new int[colcount];

    for (int v = 0; v < colcount; v++) {

        cout << "Enter Array Content [" << i << "][" << v << "] :";

        cin >> a[i][v];

        }

    }
```

**Last Update:** 
To better track contents and privileges of template class, i ended up using vectors and with the help of community, here is how i came up.

```
int n;

cout << "Enter Num of Vectors: ";

cin >> n;

vector<vector <int> > mult_arr(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    int k;

    cout << "Enter size for vec " << i << ":";

    cin >> k;

    mult_arr[i].resize(k);

    for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {

        cout << "Enter Array Contents [" << i << "][" << x << "] :";

        cin >> mult_arr[i][x];

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no multi-dimensional array in your code. A pointer is not an array!

Comment: I guess you have a good reason not to use `std::vector `?

Comment: Yes, with Vector template class its easy however i would like to get a good hold on dynamic memory allocation in C++.

Comment: You can't determine the size of an array from a pointer - you need to keep track of it separately

Comment: The Update doesn't really solve the problem, because you've still lost track of the sizes of each subarray, so it'll be difficult to use the data.  You have to keep track of the sizes somewhere.

Comment: I agree, like am lost now on how to print the contents of each array.

Comment: You shouldn't bother using dynamically allocated memory in C++ (if at all possible -- it almost always is; read that as always). A better approach would be to have an `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  This way you could use range-based for loops and directly express intent.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know or find the size of a dynamic allocated array without actually holding the size in a variable. You can not use the classic `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(type)` to find the size because the sizeof() a pointer is just its type size and not the total array size. Use std::vector or keep tracking the sizes of each dynamic array.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted. This is the correct answer. The question doesn't actually deal with a 2-D array, but an array of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays having different sizes which were not saved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pointers to pointers to `int`, consider using a single allocation. It is easier and faster!

```
int * matrix = new int[width * height];

matrix[y * width + x] = 0;

delete [] matrix;
```

Comment: If you read the OP closely, you'll see that JYasir isn't using the same width for all of the rows.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy He can still use a single allocation; just allocate the total number of elements required and calculatet the indexes into the allocated array. Acorn's example may not be appropriate here, but the idea still is. Also, he should have used `std::vector` instead and save a lot of hazzle.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Indeed, but people learning C/C++ tend to think that they have to allocate rows/columns one by one -- possibly because they learnt multi-dimensional arrays first. The pseudo-example here only shows the general principle.

Comment: Yes, you could use a single allocation for the arrays, but then you'd need a separate allocation for an array to keep track of the sizes or offsets of each the subarrays.  This answer gives partial information, but it misses the point of the question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Not necessarily -- they may still be known at compile-time; in which case you would only need a mapping to the index. Even if they aren't known, you may have other ways of keeping track of that, like using a terminator value à la string. But yes, you might want to do it using another allocation; although I am not sure how that is a problem.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Regarding the point of the question, I don't agree. I believe giving the reader other options/solutions always add to the topic, specially if he/she is learning -- which is why I wrote "*consider*". I agree it is not *exactly* what was asked, of course.

Comment: @Acorn:  The subarray sizes being known at compile time is not consistent with the OP's code sample showing the user being queried for their sizes.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Sure -- but it can still be done without allocating each individual array separately.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to rewrite your program to a more domatic C++ program (including a main function, so you can test it). Technically, this does solve the same problem, but instead of using `new` and `delete`, it uses `std::vector`, which should always be the first thing you should reach for.

Unless you have a very *very* good reason not to use vector, I advice you forget about `new`/`delete`. Know that it's there and get on with your life.

I realize this doesn't actually answer your question. I think it's too long for a comment so I'm providing it as answer instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int get_an_integer(std::string message)
{
    std::cout << message;
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

    matrix.resize(get_an_integer("Number of vectors:"));
    for (auto& vector : matrix)
    {
        vector.resize(get_an_integer("Vector size:"));
        for (auto& element : vector)
            element = get_an_integer("Element value:");
    }

    for (auto v : matrix)
    {
        for (auto e : v)
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Notice how I don't have to keep track of anything and I don't really care about the explicit size of anything. Even the values of the elements aren't interesting.

I hope this helps you. If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: I wanted to stay on dynamic memory but yeah there are more cons then pros to it. However i do appreciate your feedback's as it has provided another perspective on how to tackle these interview related questions :-) ...

Comment: If you're at a job interview where they ask you to do manual memory management, ask them if it's a trick question.

Answer (score -1):

You can memset to initialize an array. like

```
int *arr = new int[5]; 
fill(c, c + 5, 3); //fill(array, array+size, intialvalue)
cout<<c[4];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question and also wrong

Comment: he asked only for how to initialize the dynamically created array. That's why i have suggested him memset function

Comment: No, OP asked how to fill it with user provided values. Also your example code does not work for dynamically allocated arrays